# How to match column

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have made this sql from Acces database. What I wanted to create is the following:

```
Grootboekrek   omschrijving  jan    feb   maart   april  mei ......
1111111        debiteuren   10.000   500.......
```

I wanted to create in one qry in several column the data with period.

```
SELECT    qry_gb_lijst.grootboek,
      qry_gb_kmf_jan_2018.saldo   AS Jan,
      qry_gb_kmf_feb_2018.saldo   AS Feb,
      qry_gb_kmf_mrt_2018.saldo   AS Maart,
      qry_gb_kmf_april_2018.saldo AS April,
      qry_gb_kmf_mei_2018.saldo   AS Mei,
      qry_gb_kmf_juni_2018.saldo  AS Juni,
      qry_gb_kmf_juli_2018.saldo  AS Juli,
      qry_gb_kmf_aug_2018.saldo   AS Aug,
      qry_gb_kmf_sep_2018.saldo   AS Sep,
      qry_gb_kmf_okt_2018.saldo   AS Okt,
      qry_gb_kmf_nov_2018.saldo   AS Nov,
      qry_gb_kmf_dec_2018.saldo   AS [dec]
FROM      qry_gb_lijst
LEFT JOIN (((((((((((qry_gb_kmf_jan_2018
LEFT JOIN qry_gb_kmf_feb_2018
ON        qry_gb_kmf_jan_2018.grootboek = qry_gb_kmf_feb_2018.grootboek)
LEFT JOIN qry_gb_kmf_mrt_2018
ON        qry_gb_kmf_feb_2018.grootboek = qry_gb_kmf_mrt_2018.grootboek)
LEFT JOIN qry_gb_kmf_april_2018
ON        qry_gb_kmf_mrt_2018.grootboek = qry_gb_kmf_april_2018.grootboek)
LEFT JOIN qry_gb_kmf_mei_2018
ON        qry_gb_kmf_april_2018.grootboek = qry_gb_kmf_mei_2018.grootboek)
LEFT JOIN qry_gb_kmf_juni_2018
ON        qry_gb_kmf_mei_2018.grootboek = qry_gb_kmf_juni_2018.grootboek)
LEFT JOIN qry_gb_kmf_juli_2018
ON        qry_gb_kmf_juni_2018.grootboek = qry_gb_kmf_juli_2018.grootboek)
LEFT JOIN qry_gb_kmf_aug_2018
ON        qry_gb_kmf_juli_2018.grootboek = qry_gb_kmf_aug_2018.grootboek)
LEFT JOIN qry_gb_kmf_sep_2018
ON        qry_gb_kmf_aug_2018.grootboek = qry_gb_kmf_sep_2018.grootboek)
LEFT JOIN qry_gb_kmf_okt_2018
ON        qry_gb_kmf_sep_2018.grootboek = qry_gb_kmf_okt_2018.grootboek)
LEFT JOIN qry_gb_kmf_nov_2018
ON        qry_gb_kmf_okt_2018.grootboek = qry_gb_kmf_nov_2018.grootboek)
LEFT JOIN qry_gb_kmf_dec_2018
ON        qry_gb_kmf_nov_2018.grootboek = qry_gb_kmf_dec_2018.grootboek)
ON        qry_gb_lijst.grootboek = qry_gb_kmf_jan_2018.grootboek;
```

Can someone tell me why qry_gb_lijst.grootboek match wont work fully

Comment: Table definitions and sample data please. Also, can you better describe "match wont work fully"?

Comment: My first inclination was to union all 12 query results 1st and then cross tab the results; but then I saw this apperas to be build on a query.  So... Is the source data all in 1 table and would simply doing a cross tab query on it based on Month  with values from saldo work?

Comment: Please post error or undesired result as *won't work fully* is not helpful to us.

Answer (score 0):

You are *chaining* the conditions.  Instead, you need to go back to the original table each time:

```
FROM  (((((((((((qry_gb_lijst as l LEFT JOIN
                 qry_gb_kmf_jan_2018
                 ON l.grootboek = qry_gb_kmf_jan_2018.grootboek
                ) LEFT JOIN
                qry_gb_kmf_feb_2018
                ON l.grootboek = qry_gb_kmf_feb_2018.grootboek
               ) LEFT JOIN
               qry_gb_kmf_mar_2018
               ON l.grootboek = qry_gb_kmf_mar_2018.grootboek
              . . .
```

You are left joining each month to the previous month.  So, if a value disappears in month X in won't appear in any subsequent month.

Comment: Hi Gordon,Thank you. How should I do this?

Comment: @Barendrecht . . . I thought the answer was quite clear.  You need to compare the keys to `l.grootboek` in each case.  That is what is shown in this answer.